# Tiling an image in a UIVIew

Tags: iphone, image, uiview, uiimageview, tiling

I am trying to tile an image for an app I am making.  I am making rope that I can set the length for.  In order to do this, I have a function that takes my rope length, sets the frame size accordingly, and then sets the background color like this:

(picture is a `UIView`)

```
picture.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rope.png"]];
```

The view is blank.  I tested it before by displaying an image by making picture a UIImageView instead, and it worked, but it won't show up anymore.

**EDIT:**  I have now tried a few different methods of tiling, the best I can get is a stretched image.  I need a working way to tile an image and get the output of my tiled image into a `UIImage`, `UIImageView`, or `UIView`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what I did wrong but it is working now.